# C++ vs Java - Selection Sort Performances

Tags: java, c++, sorting, selection

im testing Java and C++ performances with a selection sort algorithm.

**Here's the Java code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] mArray = new int[100000];
    fillArrayRandomly(mArray, 10);

    long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selectionSort(mArray);
    long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println((timeEnd - timeStart) + "ms");
}

public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
    for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++)
        for(int j=i+1; j<array.length; j++)
            if(array[j]<array[i])
                swap(array, i, j);
}

public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp; 
}

public static void fillArrayRandomly(int array[], int maxNum) {
    Random generator = new Random(); 

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        array[i] = generator.nextInt(maxNum);
}

public static void printArray(int array[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

**Here's the C++ code:**

```
void fillArrayRandomly(int *array, int dim, int max)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<dim; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % max;
}

void selectionSort(int *array, int dim)
{
    for(int i=0; i<dim-1; i++)
        for(int j=i+1; j<dim; j++)
            if(array[i] > array[j])
                swap(array[i], array[j]);
}

int main()
{
    int DIM = 100000;
    int *array = new int[DIM];

    fillArrayRandomly(array, DIM, 100);

    long tStart = GetTickCount();
    selectionSort(array, DIM);
    long tEnd = GetTickCount(); 

    cout << tEnd-tStart << " ms" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Here's the results with an array of 100000 elements:

**C++:** 6584 ms

**Java:** 3942 ms

This sounds pretty strange in my opinion. Shouldn't the C++ code be faster than the Java one?

Can you help me solving this problem? 
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you compiling the C++ code with any optimizations enabled?

Comment: The JVM does a lot of optimization, there might be a lot potential in regards to optimization in your C++ code.

Comment: You should use the same data set, as this influences your timing (number of swaps)

Comment: My guess is you didn't turn optimizations on. Would you show your compiler options for the C++ code?

Comment: The number of swaps are pretty even (counted them) but i don't know where to find the optimization option in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: FWIW the C++ code performs faster on my machine than the Java code (I switched optimisations on), but that doesn’t mean a lot – the code you’re using has no specific advantage in either language and will perform about the same. This is not interesting code for the purpose of comparing the respective performance of these languages.

Comment: Yeah i know that is not a good example to check which one is faster but i don't know why this code is slower in C++.

Comment: @The.Coder Are you doing a debug or release build in VS 2012?

Comment: If it is debug. That could explain a lot. I have seen debug builds under Visual Studio take 100 times longer (yes 100X) than Release builds. An example of this is doing multithreaded 3D image filters with images that are 500+ MB  (Lung CT images).

Comment: Im using the release build of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters, your java code only generate random numbers until 10, and c++ is until 100, obviously there would be more swaps.. usually for this kind of testing you want to test the EXACT same array..

Comment: I tried with random numbers until 100 in Java too and the difference still 2 seconds. I will try with the same array.

Comment: Actually i tried with the same array and Java still performing better.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your c++ swap? >are you using the `template std::swap(T&x,T&y)?` This template is best for "big" types with move constructor and asignment. Try with one als in your java test using indexes.